# Cannot open JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

I have used the code below to open a json file.

```
    f = open('pathname','r')
    data = json.load(f)
    f.close()
```

However, I keep getting the error message:
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

The JSON file is formatted like below.

```
    x = [{"cap": 4.0, "opt": 14.0, "source": "Initial debugging data", "data": [[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 3.0], [1.0, 4.0], [1.0, 5.0]]}]
```

I have also tried json.loads(f) and got the same error message.
Thank you!

Comment: That isn't JSON. `x =` is not valid JSON syntax. More likely it's JavaScript.

Comment: That's not valid json.  The `x =` at the beginning does not belong.

Comment: Perhaps check the formatting of your JSON file, your code sample works for me on a valid JSON file. Note your alternative attempt should be `json.loads(f.read())`. From your sample the JSON file must start with a `{`, see `json.dumps` for comparison.

Comment: @importrandom try it with the data file they provided, the one starting with `x =`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the file is not a JSON file, so the parser is correct to reject it.